What are the injective embeddings of R^d into the cone of (semi-) positive definite matrices of dimension d?
How can we characterize the set of all injective functions from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to the set of all symmetric positive definite matrices of dimension d?

You need to specify some extra restrictions on your functions (such as continuity, or linearity) - but until you edit your question it is not clear to readers what tacit conditions you are imposing.

Since $\exp:S_d(\mathbb{R})\to S^+_d(\mathbb{R}$) is a diffeomorphism, where $S_d(\mathbb{R})$ is the vector space of symmetric $d$-by-$d$ matrices with real entries (whose dimension is $\tfrac12d(d{+}1)$), and $S^+_d(\mathbb{R})\subset S_d(\mathbb{R})$ is the open cone of positive definite symmetric $d$-by-$d$ matrices, any injection $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to S^+_d(\mathbb{R})$ is uniquely of the form $f = \exp\circ\phi$, where $\phi:\mathbb{R}^d\to S_d(\mathbb{R})$ is an injective map, so you are reduced to 'characterizing' the injective maps $\phi$ into the vector space $S_d(\mathbb{R})$.

@RobertBryant   What  can  be  said  about the topology of  space  of  all semi positive matrix of  size $d$ whose  matrix norm is  $\leq$  1? It is  compact and  convex  so is it homeomorphic  to a  disk?

More generally is  every compact  convex set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ homeomorphic  to a  $k$  dimensional disk for  some  $k\leq n$?
